# Why does enum's valueOf() return null?

Tags: java, enums

While modifying an existing application that I'm not yet entirely familiar with, I seem to have run into a situation where

```
EnumClass.valueOf(s)
```

returns `null` regardless of what `String` value I pass in (legal or not).  The `EnumClass` itself is trivial (essentially `public enum EnumClass { Name1, Name2, Name3 }`).  It behaves as expected when I try a standalone test (i.e. it either returns an object of the enum class, or throws `IllegalArgumentException`), but within the larger application it's returning null.

Are there any conditions under which this could legitimately happen?  E.g. is there a compiler option that causes a table of strings not to be generated (for space optimization purposes)?  I'm using JDK 1.7.

**EDIT:** OK, almost a month later, I finally got a chance to try to narrow down the problem.  It's related to JMockit, which we're using in conjunction with JUnit.  This is in one of the test classes:

```
@Mocked
private EnumClass2 e;
```

The JMockit tutorial says that `enum` classes can be mocked, although Java isn't supposed to let you create an instance of an `enum`; my guess is that JMockit goes through some real skulduggery to make this happen.  Anyway, it apparently doesn't happen correctly.  It appears that using this causes `valueOf` to get screwed up even for a different `enum` class with no relation to the one being mocked.  I don't know which version of JMockit we're using.

**More:** I couldn't reproduce the problem at home, so likely it has to do either with an old version of JMockit, a combination of versions of things, or customization somebody else has done.

Comment: Please post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: According to the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3), this should never happen.

Comment: Should work just fine with JDK 1.7, there may be something that we may be missing. Mind posting some code?

Comment: @ajb I made program for enum and check MyEnum.valueOf(s); where s is string. if s is not match with enum then give IllegalArgumentException otherwise it give value of enum.Are you sure s is not null?

Comment: @android_dev If `s` is null, it should throw `NullPointerException`.  In my standalone test case (which works), that is what happens.

Comment: @RC I don't know that I can post an MCVE.  To do so, I'd have to make a copy of the entire application, sanitize all the names, and then start trying to removing pieces to narrow things down--while trying to figure out how to remove dependencies on things like JUnit, JMockit, etc.  That would take much more time than I can devote to this.  I was hoping somebody knew offhand of some conditions that could cause this.

Comment: cant you just take a snippet of the enum?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in some other code sample?

Comment: "To do so, I'd have to...That would take much more time than I can devote to this."  We've got a name for all that ...:  It's called "debugging", and yeah, sometimes it takes time.  Sometimes it takes more time than an individual or an organization is willing to spend, in which case, they either learn to live with the problem, or they find some other way to deal with it.

Comment: @ajb The fact is -- as stated by Sotirios -- that this should not happen. So the chance that someone comes with an answer "I saw that before it's about x and y" is approx. 0, we don't have the context, we don't have the code..  (voting to close)

Comment: @jameslarge And one of the ways of finding another way to deal with it is to find out whether, by chance, someone has run across this before.  OK, so apparently nobody has, which I couldn't find out until I asked.  I don't see why you felt it necessary to be snide.  In all probability, I have been engaging in "debugging" since before most readers of SO were born, so I think I have a fair idea of the different possible approaches to deal with a problem.

Comment: @Zhedar Not sure what you mean by "take a snippet of the enum"... if you want to see part of the `enum` class, I mentioned in my question that it is a very basic `enum` declaration--no methods or anything.

Comment: Did you use mockstatic? it can cause this problem.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary It's been so long ago my memory is hazy, but I don't recall using "mockstatic".  I looked it up and it looks like mockstatic is a PowerMock thing, and we're using JMockit.

Comment: Thanks for recalling, I thought it might help somebody, in our case recently this was the problem, the symptoms are similar.